# What is the frequency of the cores in github codespaces

Tags: linux, github, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I have started using codespaces lately and it's a really good experience! Even with the specs of 2 cores and 4gb ram, it is a lot faster than my machine that has the exact same specs, except I don't know the speed of the core itself. Mine is 3.4ghz dual core and it struggles a lot with nextjs.

Now I know that codespaces will have no bulky apps or gui that does increases it's speed, but still that would not be this much.

Benchmarks: It took me exactly 350ms to do all the stuff in codespaces for nextjs (basic app)

It took me more than a minute and a lot of lags while setting up a nextjs app in my local machine.

So how fast exactly is the cores?

Comment: You could try `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, if that's available. But remember that CPU speed is not the only thing affecting performance. Disk speed and memory swapping can also be big factors. For example, if you're still using a spinning disk that can slow things down considerably. What might be making your application slow depends on what your application is doing.

Comment: @Schwern I did and I saw that it uses: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8272CL CPU @ 2.60GHz. So it's slower in terms of processing power, but still outperforms in a lot of aspects. I read a few threads which said that server speeds will increase because it not only has important dev tools installed, also the drivers and hardwares are latest, so yeah, there are thousands of reason why its faster.

Comment: "*So it's slower in terms of processing power*" Careful, you can't directly compare frequencies between types of chips. I'll wager you don't have a Xeon CPU. You can try comparing with https://www.cpubenchmark.net/